# Stored Procedure less than condition for nullable parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
S.Type = ISNULL(@s_type,S.Type)
```

This is the case when parameter @s_type is null it will select all the values of column S.Type
but if I want to add less than condition instead of equality, what should I do if I want to select all the values if parameter is null and select all values less than the value of parameter if it is not null ?

Comment: Show some more SQL so we can get some context around what you are trying to do please

Comment: I'm not sure whether you've other criteria but dynamic sql is the way to go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the below?

```
(S.Type < @s_type OR @s_type IS NULL)
```

If the operator is <= then it is easier :)

```
S.Type <= ISNULL(@s_type,S.Type)
```